# How to access 50+ apis in flutter app without state management?

Tags: api, flutter, dart, flutter-provider, dio

I have been building full production app and that app can be build without statemanagement yes then how?

I have been accessing over 30+ Rest apis and 50+ screens and which state management is good to go for apis datas implementation and any sample code for that?

I have thinking of using Provider is it good?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, using [BLoC](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/coreconcepts?id=bloc) is cleaner than Provider.
You can simply have UI logic and API interaction decoupled, and this makes your app more manageable and maintainable.